# How do I avoid reaching the .or() in this code?

Tags: java, option-type, java-9, flatmap

```
static final Function<Bill,Optional<LocalDate>> toDateOfInjury = b -> toClaim.andThen(opt -> opt.map(Claim::getDatInjuryDate)).apply(b); 

public static final Supplier<Optional<String>> emptyStrOpt = Optional::empty;

static final Function<Bill,Optional<String>> dateOfInjuryNotNull = b ->
            toDateOfInjury.andThen(
                    opt -> opt.flatMap(doi -> emptyStrOpt.get())
                            .or(() -> Optional.of("No date of injury"))).apply(b);
```

In a unit test, this always returns the "No date of injury" optional. I assume it is because  the empty result of flatMap triggers it. This is what I want:

- null dateOfInjury: Optional.of(".....")
- non-null dateOfInjury: Optional.empty()

Comment: What is `toDateOfInjury`? Please provide a complete example.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to do here, but there is a probably a better more clear way to code this.

Comment: Your code essentially performs `opt.flatMap(doi -> Optional::empty)`, which always triggers the `or` part. What did you expect?

Comment: `opt.map(doi -> Optional.empty()).orElseGet(() -> Optional.of("..."))`

Comment: @shmosel yes this did the trick. I will award you the answer if you post this.

Comment: or `opt.isPresent()? Optional.empty(): Optional.of("No date of injury")`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you want a simple null check. What about

```
return dateOfInjury==null?Optional.empty():Optional.of("No date of injury");
```